# Wrong output Project Euler #50 Python 3

Tags: python, math

I'm attempting [Project Euler #50](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50). It's so fun! The problem is as follows.

> The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:

```
41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13
```

> This is the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred. The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to a prime, contains 21 terms, and is equal to 953. Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes?

My code is as follows. It's written in Python 3.5.4

```
sieve = [True] * 1000000
listSieve = []
listOfNum = []
sumOfNum = 0
s = 0
for p in range(2, 1000000):
    if sieve[p]:
        listSieve.append(p)
        for i in range(p*p, 1000000, p):
            sieve[i] = False

while sumOfNum < 1000000:
    sumOfNum += listSieve[s]
    listOfNum.append(sumOfNum)
    s += 1

finalSet = list(set(listSieve) & set(listOfNum))
print(listOfNum)
print(max(finalSet))
```

Basically, it makes two lists, one of the prime numbers up to 1 million using the sieve of eratosthenes (listSieve), and the other a list of the numbers created by adding consecutive prime numbers (listOfNum). Sorry that the variable names aren't spectacular. I then cross reference the lists to find the consecutive primes, and output the highest one. The correct answer is 997651, but my program outputs 958577. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It looks like you're calculating the sum of initial sequences of primes, but that's not the question.  Why shouldn't the sequence start at 23 or whatever?

Comment: Yes, as @saulspatz said, 997651 is the sum of the 543 primes starting with 7.